# A driver operation has been interrupted (mongodb exception)

Tags: mongodb-java

I am using mongo database for my application 
for connection spooling in configured the below mongoOption while creating connection

```
MongoOptions options = new MongoOptions();
   options.autoConnectRetry = true;
   options.connectionsPerHost = 40;
   options.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 25;
```

while exceuting my application,getting the following exception

```
com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: A driver operation has been interrupted
at com.mongodb.DBPortPool.get(DBPortPool.java:216)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:440)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:177)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.update(DBApiLayer.java:349)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:177)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:817)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:785)
at cherrypick.ck.datalayer.mongo.MongoDataAccessLayer.saveObject(MongoDataAccessLayer.java:361)
at cherrypick.ck.emailinterface.CKMailMonitor.processIncomingMessage(CKMailMonitor.java:170)
at cherrypick.ck.emailinterface.CKMailMonitor.monitorNewMessages(CKMailMonitor.java:253)
at cherrypick.ck.emailinterface.CKMailMonitor.run(CKMailMonitor.java:275)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1325)
at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.tryAcquire(Semaphore.java:414)
at com.mongodb.util.SimplePool.permitAcquired(SimplePool.java:148)
at com.mongodb.util.SimplePool.get(SimplePool.java:110)
at com.mongodb.DBPortPool.get(DBPortPool.java:214)
```

could any one can help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance 
 Raja Subramani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met that problem before, it was caused by the mongo database not your code, so you can enlarge the socket-timeout in your config file or call the dba.

Comment: Provide more detail please (not the call the dba part)

Comment: I use a MongoTemplate, and define the object in xml config file. There is an option for mongo connection, which name is socket-timeout... or you just google "MongoTemplate socket-timeout"

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this exception. This happens if Thread is already interrupted and you are further trying to do some operation on same thread. I handled this exception by clearing the flag by using [Thread.interrupted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29) method of java.lang.Thread

Answer (score 0):

The same error appear when you open multiple mongodb instances. Be sure that are closing the mongo clients before open a new instance. For example:

`MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient ("localhost", 27017);`

be sure of do:

`mongo.close();`

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when using a small connection pool and overloading it with so many requests that normal functionality cannot occur. For example, I had a connection pool with a max of 10 connections, and fired off 50 requests that would each take over 10 seconds, as well as threads that were checking other mongo collections for work.