# Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool in MongDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We am seeing a strange error pasted below all of sudden in the Prod environment:

```
com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool 
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.acquirePermit(ConcurrentPool.java:186)
```

We have a plain java mongo driver version of 3.0.2.The application code is also in java and deployed in tomcat server.

Sequence of flow which is leading to the cause is :

1.Future task runs across 6 collections and tries to pull data based on certain date
2.Only one of the collection is sharded and it is splitted across three sets.Sets having a primary ,secondary and arbiter.

Is there any special consideration to be done on the connection pool or infra applied on the mongo server environment .Data which resides on the mongo is close to 150GB

Appreciate any response.

Comment: It was the same issue in my case that this problem was occurring only when debugging with IntelliJ Idea. If the exception is thrown in the code or in the normal processing flow, the problem doesn't occur.
When I remove debugger from that point, it went fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A driver operation has been interrupted (mongodb exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404717/a-driver-operation-has-been-interrupted-mongodb-exception)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when called `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`

There is even a closed ticket in Jira https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2091 which says

> the thread has already been interrupted when the mongo call is made

and

> it Works as Designed.

The other question is whether this is correct design, since calling `interrupt()` on a Thread considered to be the right practice.

I'm not sure that's your case, though.

Comment: I put some calls to Thread.currentThread().interrupt() to please my SonarQube and see the error too. Thanks for making the link.

Comment: Did you mean `calling interrupt() on a Thread IS NOT considered to be the right practice`?

Comment: @asgs there was no mistake :) why do you think it's a bad practice?

Comment: @AlexBoyarintsev please ignore. I don't remember why I posted that comment :-)

Answer (score 5):

For all those coming across this question:

It happens to me that this problem is arising only when debugging with IntelliJ Idea. If the exception is thrown in the code or in the normal processing flow, the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: I have the same problem in IntelliJ

Comment: Not sure, but it might help to try to set your break point to only suspend the current thread (right click on the break point for this setting) instead of all threads