# Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null during a Mongo save operation using JPA & Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, interrupted-exception

I have a program that performs a loop of 10K of "save" operations into a MongoDB, using the standard Spring Data `CrudRepository`.

This program run without issues and saved tens of thousands of items, until it suddenly got this exception:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool 
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.acquirePermit(ConcurrentPool.java:203)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.get(ConcurrentPool.java:140)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.get(ConcurrentPool.java:123)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.PowerOfTwoBufferPool.getBuffer(PowerOfTwoBufferPool.java:78)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:105)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:587)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:444)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:298)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:258)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:500)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:224)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:202)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeCommand(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:419)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeBulkWriteBatch(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:245)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.access$700(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:71)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:189)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:180)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:500)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:180)
at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:71)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:207)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1008)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeReplaceOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:566)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.replaceOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:549)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$saveDocument$17(MongoTemplate.java:1517)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:566)
... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.acquirePermit(ConcurrentPool.java:199)
... 70 common frames omitted
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404717/a-driver-operation-has-been-interrupted-mongodb-exception/34410162#34410162) it is suggested that it may be something in the Mongo itself, but this post is 5 years old. Also, there are suggestion in there that are not relevant.

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A driver operation has been interrupted (mongodb exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404717/a-driver-operation-has-been-interrupted-mongodb-exception)

Comment: Hi @JensSchauder. This is the same link as I used in the post. :-)  It didn't help me.

Comment: I'm aware. If a question didn't get a good answer, the right thing to do is to post a bounty, not to ask basically the same question again.